# chart.js: Missing class properties transform

Tags: reactjs, npm, frontend, chart.js, npm-package

how can I overcome (https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hDX7.jpg)

This error occurred when I pull the code from GitHub. one of my peer using chart.js for his part. after that I have installed the packages using 'npm i' but it doesn't worked. how can I fix this error

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.